# Независимое текущее время в Java (Android)

Tags: java, android, время

Пишу приложение, логика которого требует подключаться к серверу для обновления раз в год. Но дата в системе пользователя может быть установлена неверно, из-за чего есть вероятность возникновения ошибок. Вопрос вот в чём: как этого избежать? Есть ли какой-то несложный способ без лишних расходов заряда аккумулятора устройства получать независимое от пользовательского время? Или же проще пересмотреть архитектуру?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Так как вы говорите, что контроля над часами клиента у вас нет, то подключайтесь раз в сутки/неделю/месяц и проверяйте на сервере, обновляли вы этого клиента в этом году или еще нет. Ну и добавьте кнопку в интерфейсе "проверить наличие обновлений" для ручной проверки.

Answer (score 2):

Нельзя в android'е завязываться на системное время, много с этим нахватались

Можно сделать запрос на сервер, проверяющий не вышла ли новая версия, либо использовать push-уведомление